# Yeoman AngularJS generate route in specific subfolder?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular

I would like to know if it's possible to create a route - That also generates a controller and a view- with yeoman in a specific subfolder? i mean, i would like to create a route under the subfolder `FAQ` so that i'll create a subfolder under views and under controllers.

I think that the command would be:

```
yo angular:route FAQ/faq
```

I tested it, and it works, but is that correct?, how could i open the mand of yo angular, or the help?

Also would like to know if there's a command to delete the complete route?